# Transistor Q's: Switching a Positive V when Base goes negative (and the other way 'round)

Tags: transistors, switching

I thought I knew enough to get this working, but apparently I don't...

I have a waveform going between +5 and -5V at audio rates.

When the waveform is above 0V, I want to charge a capacitor from -15V rail at 20mA.
When the waveform is below 0V, I want to charge a capacitor from +15V rail at 20mA.

The cutoff point doesn't have to be right at 0V, it can be a diode drop above (or below) that. I have a Bipolar power supply of +/- 15V.

I can get it working the opposite (charge positive cap when Voltage goes high) and I know I can just use an op-amp to invert the incoming signal, but I'm sure it can be done without adding additional parts..

Comment: Show us what you are doing now and maybe we can give you some pointers on how to change it to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just a pointer: If you connect your audio signal to the negative input terminal of an OPAMP without feedback (i.e. a comparator) and the positive input to 0V, it will output the requested polarity voltage. All you must do now is to add two current sources for 20mA charging.